# subprocess + grep for backslash terminated string

Tags: python, bash, grep, subprocess

I want to use subprocess to grep for a string that end in backslash:

```
product = "myProduct\"
```

so in bash, if I do:

```
zgrep -n 'myProduct\\' file_of_products.txt.gz
```

it works (I get a bunch of lines). Trying now in python:

```
import subprocess
product = "myProduct\\"
command = f"""zgrep -n "{product}" {filename}"""
return_code, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(command)
```

I get;

```
'/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string'
```

Comment: try: `product = r"myProduct\\"`

Comment: That was my guess too. I did. I get: `'/bin/grep: Trailing backslash'` (I should have specified in the question)

Comment: You should probably try 4 backslashes in Python. `\\` is the escape character, `\\` is a literal backslash. You need 2 in bash so 4 in Python.

Comment: Then try: `command = f"zgrep -n '{product}' '{filename}'"`

Comment: @anubhava: works perfect. Thanks sire. Would you mind posting it an an answer?

Comment: @KostasMouratidis: I tried that too. Grep accepts it, but it is a different grep querry (equivalent to grepping for "myProduct\\\\"

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this refactored code with raw string and single quoting:

```sh
import subprocess
product = r"myProduct\\"
command = f"zgrep -n '{product}' '{filename}'"
return_code, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(command)
```